# How do I do math with colors like SASS but in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, colors, hex, sass

In SASS I can do:

```
!pink = #ff43a7
!darker_pink = !pink - #333333
```

I'd like to the same in Ruby.

Comment: I'm confused about the application of this; SASS is build in Ruby. Are you talking about doing this in ERb?

Answer (score 4):

Hex can be represented in Ruby by prefixing your value with `0x`:

```
pink = 0xff43a7
darker_pink = pink - 0x333333
```

#### color helper

```
def color(hex)
  "#%06x" % hex
end
```

#### Usage in ERb template

```
.container {
  color: <%= color pink %>;
  border: 1px solid <%= color darker_pink %>;
}
```

#### Output

```
.container {
  color: #ff43a7;
  border: 1px solid #cc1074;
}
```

Comment: You have to add bounds checking to pin channel values at 0 and 255.

Comment: You should be using `#%06x` instead of just `#%x`. Otherwise, colors that start with zeroes will be formatted incorrectly. For example, a value of `0x000fff` would result in `#fff` (i.e. white, in CSS).

Comment: I agree with @drawnonward; without channel clamping, the result of `0x010000 - 0x000001` is probably not what's expected when the intent is, "removed a bit of blue from this color."

Answer (score 2):

The basic approach of adding/subtracting colors in Sass is nonsense and only really works when using a gray adjustment. That's why in Sass 3 we now have full support of operations in the HSL domain which maps closely to the way people think about colors.

Since Sass is written in Ruby, you can at least read our code to see what's going on.

Here's the [Color class](http://github.com/nex3/haml/blob/master/lib/sass/script/color.rb), and the [functions that operate on them](http://github.com/nex3/haml/blob/master/lib/sass/script/functions.rb).

It really is non-trivial code. Why not just use Sass?

Answer (score 2):

## Use the Sass module

If you already have the Sass library, you can instantiate and work with its objects.

For instance:

```
red  = Sass::Script::Color.new([255, 0, 0])
gray = Sass::Script::Color.new([128, 128, 128])
red.lightness < gray.lightness # => true
```

There must be a built-in way to turn hexadecimal strings like `#00FF00` into `Color` objects, but not seeing one, I wrote this function:

```
# @param color_string - hex string, like '#22FF22'. MUST be 6 characters,
# because I don't feel like dealing with the use-case for 3. :)
def color_from_hex_string(color_string)
  # Drop the leading '#', if any
  color_string = color_string[1..-1] if color_string.start_with?('#')
  raise ArgumentError.new('Hex string must be 6 characters') unless color_string.length == 6

  # Turn into array of 2-digit decimal numbers. 
  # Eg, '808080' becomes [128, 128, 128]; '#ff0000' becomes [255, 0, 0]
  rgb_array = color_string.split('').each_slice(2).map do |slice|
    slice.join('').to_i(16).to_s(10)
  end

  # Use that to build a new Color object
  color = Sass::Script::Color.new(rgb_array)

  # Set this option so it won't complain (?)
  color.options = {:style => :compressed}

  return color
end
```

Comment: `color_string = color_string[1..-1] if color_string.start_with?('#')` can become `color_string.sub!(/^(?:#|0?x)/, '')`

Comment: `rgb_array = color_string.split('').each_slice(2).map` can become `color_string.scan(/../).map` and `slice.join('').to_i(16).to_s(10)` can become `slice.hex.to_s(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

To refine @macek's answer, following @drawnownward's and @lpsquiggle's wishes:

You can make two helpers, like so:

```
  def color(color)
    "#%06x" % color
  end

  def darker_color(color)
    x = color.match(/0x(..)(..)(..)/)
    r = x[1].sub(/[0-3]/, '5')
    g = x[2].sub(/[0-3]/, '5')
    b = x[3].sub(/[0-3]/, '5')
    rgb = "0x#{r}#{g}#{b}"
    "#%06x" % (rgb.hex - 0x444444)
  end
```

The advantage: if you've defined a color hex with low values (between 0 and 3, here), these will be bumped up before the subtraction, so that they end up as 0 afterward, instead of wrapping around and becoming c, d, e, or f (which would give you a color you didn't expect). It only does this for the first value in each #rrggbb pair, so #313131 becomes #0d0d0d, which isn't technically correct, but it's much better than #fdfdfd, so it seems like a good enough compromise, since you'll want to keep those second values in other cases.

In your Erb template, then, you would write this:

```
.container {
  color: <%= color pink %>;
  border: 1px solid <%= darker_color pink %>;
}
```

Instead of:

```
.container {
  color: <%= color pink %>;
  border: 1px solid <%= color darker_pink %>;
}
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Looks like the first five lines of the `darker_color` method can be replaced with `rgb = color[/^0x(.{6})/, 1].tr('0-3', '5')`

Answer (score 0):

I just came across something where I wanted to distribute colors for a set across different hues.  The SASS source didn't help much because I didn't see a way to get RGB from HSV.

The [color gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/color) had what I needed.

I wrote this helper:

```
def region_color(index, size)
  h = (index.to_f / (size - 1).to_f)
  Color::HSL.from_fraction(h, 0.95, 0.3).html
end
```